# Wireframe Box with Helix-toolkit.Wpf

Tags: c#, helix-3d-toolkit

I was wondering if it is possible to draw a wireframe box with helix-toolkit.wpf. If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a model you can set RenderWireframe to true. Following code generates a simple tile model at position x,y. This can be applied to more complex models to.

```
var model = new MeshGeometryModel3D();
var meshBuilder = new MeshBuilder();
meshBuilder.AddBox(new Rect3D(x, y, 0, width, height, 0.0), BoxFaces.PositiveZ);
MeshGeometry3D geometry = meshBuilder.ToMeshGeometry3D();
model.Geometry = geometry;
model.RenderWireframe = true;
```

Comment: MeshGeometryModel3D does not seem to exist in HelixToolkit.Wpf